# eth :: -F and --farm always produce Invalid argument: when attempting to pool mine

Tags: cpp-ethereum, mining-pools

How can I launch a pool mining session using the most recent cpp-ethereum?

According to the ./eth --help, -F or --farm parameters are needed, but they are not recognized when used!

I have a recent successful build and installation of 'eth' on OpenSuSE, and can successfully launch 'eth' as described in the Homestead doc, page 64:

/opt/eth/bin/eth -v 1 -a 0x.MYWALLET --client-name "Oxymoron" -x 50 -m on -t 1
,resulting in a stream of DAG or Block Import messages, and saturated 100% usage of all CPUs.  ethconsole works too.

But no mining pool can be specified, as it immediately returns: 
Invalid argument: --farm  or -F as if it was some arbitrary invalid string like -G.

$/opt/eth/bin/eth -V

- eth version 1.3.0,
- eth network protocol version: 63,
- Client database version: 12041,
- Build: Linux/g++/Interpreter/.

wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww

edit:  This feels a lot like a programming logic problem, like somebody commented out some switch's 'case' statement.  Does anyone know if v 1.3.0 has been explicitly set to not support pooled mining?

Comment: Hi there. What's the exact command you're running when the error is hit?

Comment: Generally any otherwise valid command, with either/or -F or --farm-recheck and their parameters.     An example would be:  opt/eth/bin/eth -v 1 -a 0x003238af8ab9f73235e5693574fe41173ccede21 --client-name "Oxymoron" -x 50 -m on --farm-recheck 400 -F http://eth-us.dwarfpool.com:80

Comment: Also, I assume the old 'ethminer' has been deprecated by functionality supposedly now in the 'eth' application.  No separate 'ethminer' is produced during make, and I have found no cmake parameters to explicitly create an 'etherminer' application (vs just 'eth').

Comment: And, looking through the source with 'vi' and 'find . -name *.cpp (OR *.h) | xargs grep "string" * '  doesn't show any parsing which would process either a '--farm' or '-F' token either.  Those are just mentioned in cout's in the MiningAux.h header, maybe to be appended to 'eth --help' output somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Mining

This project is **not suitable for Ethereum mining**. The support for GPU mining 
has been dropped some time ago including the ethminer tool. Try using
the fork https://github.com/genoil/cpp-ethereum.